# how to build LSTM RNN network for binary classification?

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to build a deep learning network for binary classification using LSTM based RNN.

Here is what I have tried using python

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.layers import Embedding
from keras.layers import LSTM
import numpy as np

train = np.loadtxt("TrainDatasetFinal.txt", delimiter=",")
test = np.loadtxt("testDatasetFinal.txt", delimiter=",")

y_train = train[:,7]
y_test = test[:,7]

train_spec = train[:,6]
test_spec = test[:,6]


model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(8, 256, input_length=1))
model.add(LSTM(output_dim=128, activation='sigmoid',
               inner_activation='hard_sigmoid'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')

model.fit(train_spec, y_train, batch_size=2000, nb_epoch=11)
score = model.evaluate(test_spec, y_test, batch_size=2000)
```

Here is a sample from the dataset

(Patient Number, time in millisecond, accelerometer x-axis,y-axis,
z-axis,magnitude, spectrogram,label (0 or 1))

```
1,15,70,39,-970,947321,596768455815000,0
1,31,70,39,-970,947321,612882670787000,0
1,46,60,49,-960,927601,602179976392000,0
1,62,60,49,-960,927601,808020878060000,0
1,78,50,39,-960,925621,726154800929000,0
```

I believe that the my problem in those lines but I cannot recognize the error

```
model.add(Embedding(8, 256, input_length=1))
model.add(LSTM(output_dim=128, activation='sigmoid',
               inner_activation='hard_sigmoid'))
```

and this is the error I have got

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): indices[0,0] = -2147483648 is not in [0, 8)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the sample from your dataset provided above, the data you are trying to feed into the model? If so, there is a problem because your data is 2-dimensional, but for an RNN you need a 3-dimensional input tensor. You need a feature dimension, a batch size dimension and a time dimension. It looks like you are missing a proper time dimension. You should not have a column with 15, 31, 46,... (time in milliseconds) this should be shaped into its own dimension, so your input data looks like a "cube". Otherwise, you don't need a temporal model at all. Furthermore, you should standardize your input since your features have vastly different orders of magnitude. Moreover, the batch size of 2000 is almost certainly too large. Are you trying to express that your whole training set has 2000 samples? In this case, you may not have enough training data for the model you are building.

Comment: yes the dataset i'm using is feed into the model but not all of it i just feed the spectrogram column and the label

Comment: i used 2000 samples because the total train samples are 1,415,684

Comment: how to standardize the input

Comment: So, your input only has one input feature (spectrogram) and one binary output feature? Doesn't your model expect 8 inputs, though? I haven't worked with Keras in a while, but maybe set Embedding(1,256,...), instead Embedding(8,256,...)? If you want to model this as a time series, you'd probably still have to cut it into time slices of, say length 100, so your dimensions are features = 1, batch size =2000, time = 100. Standardizing input means you subtract mean and divide by standard deviation, so your columns all have mean 0 and standard deviation of 1. This improves learning.

Comment: yes the input feature is the spectrogram and output label is (0 or 1)

Comment: thank you for your help ,, but in the input _length what value should i put ?

Comment: I'm not sure. What happens if you remove the Embedding layer altogether? I don't think you need this. Just put the LSTM layer, set  return_sequences=true, and experiment with input_dim (likely =1), input_length (try the number of training samples). Lastly don't set batch_size anywhere. Does this at least run?

Comment: ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_2: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

Comment: model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=(1415684, 8)))
model.add(LSTM(64, input_dim=1, input_length=1415684, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')

model.fit(train_spec, y_train, batch_size=2000, nb_epoch=11)
score = model.evaluate(test_spec, y_test, batch_size=2000)

Comment: I think at this point, you should probably post your question here: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues they will be able to help you.